# Finding runtime of recursive algorithms

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime, big-o

I'm trying to find runtime for this algorithm (for finding kth smallest value in an array):

```
Select(A[1 . . . n], k) if n ≤ 100 then
  Return the k-th smallest element via brute-force; else
  Divide A into m ← ⌈n/3⌉ consecutive subgroups of size at most 3; 
  for i ← 1 . . . m do
    M[i] ← Median of the i-th subgroup;
  end
  p ← Select(M[1...m],⌊m/2⌋);
  Let B be an array contains all the elements < p in A;
  Let C be an array contains all the elements ≥ p in A;
  if len(B) ≥ k then
    return Select(B,k);
  else
    return Select(C, k − len(B));
  end
end
```

I tried to come up with a recurrence relation in order to find the runtime. This is what I think it is :

Since the algorithm makes recursive calls on n/3 elements of the array, I expect it to be 2T(n/3) + O(n). And then apply master's theorem. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: What is `m2` or `n3` in this pseudocode? Also, what dodes the algorithm compute? Is it a variant of [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)  or maybe [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) ?

Comment: @wsdookadr sorry, that was a typo, m2 is actually m/2 and n3 is n/3, I corrected it above. It is an algorithm for finding kth smallest value in an array

Comment: Hint: this is a well-known algorithm, that was specifically designed to ensure complexity O(N) of the median selection.